# How can I display notifications with a Windows Service Application in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, windows-services

I have a vb.net windows service that sends emails automatically getting the addresses from a sql server database but I want that this service sends notifications if the email has not been sent or if it was sent or if it didn't found the file that was supposed to be in the email.

The question is how can I achieve this? I know that windows services cannot interact with the system tray that's why I'm having a hard time figuring this one out. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: "... I want that this service sends notifications ...".  What does that actually mean?  What exactly are you expecting to happen?

Comment: i'm sorry english is not my primary language, i mean that the service displays notifications like when Java needs to update and a little yellow rectangle pops up in the right corner of the screen you know? something like that...is it too difficult? thank you

Comment: It's not something that I've ever done but this is where I'd start: https://www.google.com.au/search?q=windows+service+interact+with+desktop+vb.net

Comment: Thanks for your help I really appreciate it